# Django: TruncYear and annotate/aggregate?

Tags: python, django

I'm having the following model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    placed_at = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.DecimalField()
```

And I want to know the total of `amount` for each year. When running:

```
Order.objects.annotate(year=TruncYear('placed_at'))
             .values('year')
             .annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
```

Django returns a queryset with the year and total for every record in the database (so `total == amount`). When using aggregate:

```
Order.objects.annotate(year=TruncYear('placed_at'))
             .values('year')
             .aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))
```

Django returns the grand total (`{'total': Decimal('72822.41')}`). The result I'm looking for should be the total broken down per year. Like

```
<QuerySet [{'year': 2016, 'total': Decimal('20000.00')},
           {'year': 2017, 'total': Decimal('30000.00')}]
```

Any idea what I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to bet that you have a default ordering specified on your `Order` model, which [would cause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) the behaviour you are seeing. You need to clear the default ordering when you make the query:

```
Order.objects.annotate(year=TruncYear('placed_at'))
         .values('year')
         .annotate(total=Sum('amount')).order_by()
```

Note the `order_by()`.